# rake db:migrate rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite3-ruby

Would be very grateful if someone could help at least to understand where the issue could be coming from.

I'm having problems with migration with the project I'm working on. I even started a brand new one but the issue is still assuring the same. Error messages appearing on attempts to do rake db:migrate
(have tried both starting new project with the default database- sqlite3 and the optional- postgresql ), however, after generating a model (tried both with rails g scaffold Schedule name:name dep_date:datetime and just model - rails g model Schedule name:name dep_date:datetime ) migration stays down.

the migration itself is:

```
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
   create_table :schedules do |t|
     t.name :name
     t.datetime :dep_date
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

command: `rake db:migrate:status`

gives the following:

```
database: travel_t_challenge_development

Status Migration ID Migration Name

down 20160809121048 Create schedules
```

commands:

```
rake db:migrate 

rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate or

rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20160809121048 or

bundle exec rake db:migrate VERSION=20160809121048
```

(or redo)

result in the same error:

```
== 20160809121048 CreateSchedules: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:schedules)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/Users/[username]/workspace/travel_t_challenge/db/migrate/20160809121048_create_schedules.rb:4:in block in change' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:277:increate_table'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in block in method_missing' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:inblock in say_with_time'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in say_with_time' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:inmethod_missing'
/Users/[username]/workspace/travel_t_challenge/db/migrate/20160809121048_create_schedules.rb:3:in change' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:inexec_migration'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in block (2 levels) in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:inblock in migrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in with_connection' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:inmigrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:inblock in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in block in ddl_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:inblock in transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in within_new_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:intransaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:inddl_transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in execute_migration_in_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:inblock in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in each' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:inmigrate_without_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in block in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:inwith_advisory_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:inup'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:989:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:inmigrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in'
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/Users/[username]/workspace/travel_t_challenge/db/migrate/20160809121048_create_schedules.rb:4:in block in change' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:277:increate_table'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in block in method_missing' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:inblock in say_with_time'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in say_with_time' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:inmethod_missing'
/Users/[username]/workspace/travel_t_challenge/db/migrate/20160809121048_create_schedules.rb:3:in change' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:inexec_migration'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in block (2 levels) in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:inblock in migrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in with_connection' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:inmigrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:inblock in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in block in ddl_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:inblock in transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in within_new_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:intransaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:inddl_transaction'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in execute_migration_in_transaction' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:inblock in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in each' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:inmigrate_without_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in block in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:inwith_advisory_lock'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:inup'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:989:in migrate' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:inmigrate'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in'
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Dropping and setting up/creating the database again hasn't helped either.

System configuration

Rails version:5.0.0
Ruby version:2.2.3

Comment: `t.name :name` => `t.string :name`

Comment: thank you @lusketeer apologies- it was me all along

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replace your change method of CreateSchedules migration.

```
def change
   create_table :schedules do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.datetime :dep_date
     t.timestamps null: false
   end
end
```